# Pandas DataFrame conditional selection with list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with 15 columns named 0,1,2,...,14. I would like to write a method that would take in this data, and a vector of length 15. I would like it to return dataframe conditionally selected based on this vector that I have passed. E.g. the data passed is data_ and the vector passed is v_
I would like to produce that:

```
data[(data[0] == v_[0]) & (data[1] == v_[1]) & ... & (data[14] == v_[14])]
```

However I would like the method to be flexible, e.g. I could pass in dataframe of 100 columns named 0, ..., 99 and a vector of length 99. My problem is that I do not know how to cleverly create `[(data[0] == v_[0]) & (data[1] == v_[1]) & ... & (data[14] == v_[14])]` programatically to account for "&" sign. Equally well I would be satisfied if someone gave me a method that could merge multiple NxM matrices filled with True and False on "and" or "or" into single MxN matrix.

Thank You very much!

Comment: if v_ is an array of same size as the number of columns, you can try `data[(data==v_).all(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def custom_filter(data, v):
    if len(data.columns) == len(v):
        # If data has the same number of columns
        #  as v has elements
        mask = (data == v).all(axis=1)
    else:
        # If they have a different length, we'll need to subset
        #  the data first, then create our mask
        #  This attempts to susbet the dataframe by assuming columns
        #    0 .. len(v) - 1 exist as columns, and will throw an error
        #    otherwise
        colnames = list(range(len(v)))
        mask = (data[colnames] == v).all(axis=1)
    
    return data.loc[mask, :]
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "F": list("hiadsfin"),
    0: list("aaaabbbb"),
    1: list("cccdddee"),
    2: list("ffgghhij")
})
v = ["a", "c", "f"]

df
   F  0  1  2  H
0  h  a  c  f  1
1  i  a  c  f  2
2  a  a  c  g  3
3  d  a  d  g  4
4  s  b  d  h  5
5  f  b  d  h  6
6  i  b  e  i  7
7  n  b  e  j  8
```

```
custom_filter(df, v)
   F  0  1  2  H
0  h  a  c  f  1
1  i  a  c  f  2
```

Note that with this function, if the number of columns exactly matches the length of your vector `v`, then you do not need to ensure the columns are labelled as `0, 1, 2, ..., len(v)-1`. However if you have more columns than elements of v, you need to ensure that a subset of those columns are labelled as `0, 1, 2, ..., len(v)-1. If` v` is longer than there are columns in your dataframe, this will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
data[(data==v_.transpose())].dropna(axis=1)
```